# i need to find logic to add new table for sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

```
user table
id: 1 , name: messi;
id: 2 , name: Alex;

room table
id 1, name: song;
id: 2, name: game;

chat data 
  userId:  2, first_seen: 1671471509, roomId: 1;
  userId:  2, first_seen: 1671471510, roomId: 1;
  userId:  2, first_seen: 167147151, roomId: 2;

new table I want to create this
  userId:  2, first_seen: 1671471509, last_seen: 167147151, roomId: 1;
```

Alex was in the singing room on 1671471509.
He was in the singing room on 1671471510, he was in the game room on 167147151.

Alex seen for the first time in the singing room 1671471509,

that was the last time he was seen 167147151,

because when he moved to another room, the previous room was seen for the last time.

I want to create a new table and print the first and last seen of users in the room

how can I do that?

Comment: Please describe better your question. Take a look here, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74885047/for-each-10-minutes-sequelize-table-summary-for-my-table